# Missing Camel-DNS

Tags: apache-camel, apache-servicemix

I am running on servicemix 4.4.1. I cannot locate the `camel-dns` module.

I have run `features:list` and `osgi:list`, and I do not see `camel-dns`. When I perform a

```
<to uri="dns:lookup"/>
```

I get a

```
org.apache.camel.ResolveEndpointFailedException: Failed to resolve endpoint:
dns://lookup due to: No component found with scheme: dns
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay it was a bit more tricky to get working out of the box with SMX, as the SMX does not expose a package from the JVM that the DNS bundle need. So you will get an error like this:

```
ERROR: Error starting file:bundles/dnsjava_2.1.1.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle dnsjava [69]: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=sun.net.spi.nameservice))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle dnsjava [69]: Unable to resolve 69.0: missing requirement [69.0] package; (package=sun.net.spi.nameservice)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3404)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1714)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1143)
    at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:264)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:680)
```

So you need to adjust the configuration of the SMX, in the etc/jre.properties

Add the following

```
sun.net.spi.nameservice
```

To the Java platform packages exported, for example my file now ends with

```
 org.xml.sax, \
 org.xml.sax.ext, \
 org.xml.sax.helpers, \
 sun.net.spi.nameservice
```

You would need to restart the ESB to have this change take effect.

To install the camel-dns, you need first to install its required dependencies which is junit also. Which is this bundle here: http://repo2.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/servicemix/bundles/org.apache.servicemix.bundles.junit/4.10_1/

On a basic Apache Karaf 2.2.5 I managed to get it installed

```
karaf@root> osgi:list
START LEVEL 100 , List Threshold: 50
   ID   State         Blueprint      Spring    Level  Name
[  49] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] Apache ServiceMix :: Bundles :: junit (4.10.0.1)
[  50] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] dnsjava (2.1.1)
[  65] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-core (2.10.0.SNAPSHOT)
[  66] [Active     ] [Created     ] [       ] [   50] camel-karaf-commands (2.10.0.SNAPSHOT)
[  73] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] geronimo-jta_1.1_spec (1.1.1)
[  74] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   50] camel-spring (2.10.0.SNAPSHOT)
[  75] [Active     ] [            ] [       ] [   60] camel-dns (2.10.0.SNAPSHOT)
[  76] [Active     ] [            ] [Started] [   60] IPCheck.xml (0.0.0)
```

And I copied the IPCheck.xml Camel sample route, from here:
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-dns/src/test/resources/
, to the deploy directory and have the Camel application startup:

```
karaf@root> camel:context-list 
Name                 Status               Uptime              
[camel             ] [Started           ] [22.339 seconds    ]
karaf@root> camel:context-info camel 
Camel Context camel
    Name: camel
    Version: 2.10-SNAPSHOT
    Status: Started
    Uptime: 25.835 seconds

Advanced
    Auto Startup: true
    Starting Routes: false
    Suspended: false
    Tracing: true

Properties

Components
    direct
    mock
    dns
    spring-event

Endpoints
    direct://start
    dns://ip
    mock://result
    spring-event://default

Routes
    IPCheck
```

Comment: Hi Claus, thank you for your help! I was able to follow your example and get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Not all 3rd party libraries is OSGi compliant, and therefore we cannot include a features for such components. However you can try installing the JAR as wrapped bundle yourself. I think an issue with the DNS was that its SUN JDK dependent or something like that.

See the wrap deployer: http://karaf.apache.org/manual/2.2.5/users-guide/deployer.html

See the pom.xml file of the camel-dns component to see which dependencies it requires at runtime: https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/camel/trunk/components/camel-dns/pom.xml

However it seems a recent release of dnsjava is now OSGi bundle.
So we could possible add a feature for it, so expect this in the next Camel release.

You can install it manually in your SMX with

```
osgi:install mvn:dnsjava/dnsjava/2.1.1
```

And then the camel-dns bundle

```
 osgi:install mvn:org.apache.camel/camel-dns/2.9.0
```

Mind use the correct Camel version, i typed in 2.9.0. But SMX 4.4.1 may use 2.9.1, I cannot remember.

Comment: The dnsjava bundle depends on a sun API which is most likely not exported by the ESB